# How to show unique data in listview android

Tags: java, android

My Listview data duplicates when i reload activity or moving back to related activity. But when I login from application after logout, it retains unique data.

when I debug my code, I realize the cursor of database retains previous values. how to resolve this?

Here's My Code :

```
public void setadapter() {
    boolean checkFirstTime = false;

    Log.e("Set Adapter call>>>>>", "called");
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    Database1 db = new Database1(getActivity());
    Cursor cursor = db.getWritableDatabase().query("timelinedata", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    System.out.println("Size of Cursor" + cursor.getCount());
    TImelineTask.contactList.clear();
    TImelineTask.contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("id", cursor.getString(0));
        map.put("sms", cursor.getString(1));
        map.put("phoneno", cursor.getString(2));
        map.put("date_time", cursor.getString(3));
        map.put("type", cursor.getString(4));
        map.put("source", cursor.getString(5) + " ");
        map.put("imagepath", cursor.getString(6));
        map.put("imageadd", cursor.getString(7) + "");
        map.put("issue_type", cursor.getString(8) + "");
        map.put("issue_select_type", cursor.getString(9));
        map.put("issuetype", cursor.getString(9));
        map.put("date", cursor.getString(10));
        map.put("time", cursor.getString(11));

        if (getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("caseid").equalsIgnoreCase(cursor.getString(13))) {

            TImelineTask.contactList.add(map);
        }


    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    db.close();
    if (checkFirstTime) {
        if (TImelineTask.contactList.size() > 0) {
            TImelineTask.contactList.clear();
        }
    }


    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    for (int i = 0; i < TImelineTask.contactList.size() - 1; i++) {
        try {
            Date date1 = sdf.parse(TImelineTask.contactList.get(i).get("date_time"));
            swappos = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < TImelineTask.contactList.size(); j++) {
                Date date2 = sdf.parse(TImelineTask.contactList.get(j).get("date_time"));

                if (date1.compareTo(date2) < 0) {

                    Collections.swap(TImelineTask.contactList, swappos, j);
                    date1 = date2;

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    Log.e("Adapter ", "calling");
    System.out.println("Adapter Size" + TImelineTask.contactList.size());
    listadapter = new ListAdapterClass(TImelineTask.contactList, getActivity(), this);


    listview.setAdapter(listadapter);
    listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    if (listadapter.isEmpty()) {
        noentry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        noentry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    new MyTimerTask().execute();
    checkFirstTime = true;
}
```

Comment: Clear your list before you added data in list.

Comment: @Piyush I tried it,but not happened anything.

Comment: Is there any duplicated  data in your  database?

Comment: make sure `TImelineTask.contactList` is clean, before you  `TImelineTask.contactList.add(map);`

Comment: You have to clear your listview before set a new listadapter as adapter. You're clearing your arraylist everytime but you're not clearing your listview. That might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can override OnPause() or OnStart() method of the activity for clearing your list.

Read about lifecycle of an Activity [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

I caught my mistake ..Actually database cursor is getting previous value so it replicates data.